# Better implementation for removing certain edges in Networkx

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am working with a graph in which the edges can be of two types. There is no restriction on how the two types are connected.

In the work that I am doing, I am taking a subgraph from this and want to delete only those edges which is one of the two types.

I have added the type as an edge attribute and tried to make a filter those edges using list comprehension and delete as given below:

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.path_graph(3)

In [3]: nx.set_edge_attributes(G,'B', '_type')

In [4]: G.add_edge(2, 3, _type="A")

In [5]: SG = G.subgraph([1,2,3])

In [6]: to_remove = [(a,b) for a,b,c in SG.edges(data=True) if c['_type']=="A"]

In [6]: to_remove
Out[6]: [(2, 3)]

In [7]: SG.remove_edges_from(to_remove)

In [8]: SG.edges(data=True)
Out[8]: EdgeDataView([(1, 2, {'_type': 'B'})])
```

Is there a better way to implement it either

1. without adding the types as an attribute or
2. more efficient way of implementation than above

Comment: Do you know the types of the edges before creating the graph? Or do you determine the type of an edge based on the graph with all edges?

Comment: I know the types of the edges before creating the graph.

Comment: In that case why do you not simply construct the graph with only the needed types of edges? Or do you need the full graph?

Comment: I did get your intuition and have updated the question. Actually I am taking a subgraph from the actual graph and do this operation on that. The above example is a simple one, but the graph I am working on is complicated. So I missed these relevant information in the truncation. :)

Comment: And these subgraphs are not defined before-hand.

Comment: I already thought that probably you need the full graph ;) Currently I am thinking about creating a graph for each of your edge type. As long as you only need to generate a subgraph, this would work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192421/discussion-between-ggjon-and-sparky05).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to do this multiple times, you may can improve the performance by creating three graphs.

1. The graph with all edges
2. The graph with edges of type A
3. The graph with edges of type B

Instead of filtering, you simply generate the subgraph of the needed graph. The complexity for filtering is probably something like O(|E_subgraph|+|V_subgraph|) in comparison to filtering, which takes O(|E|), and deleting O(|E_selected|).

You can compare both approaches with `timeit`, if you want to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Networkx nodes and edges has no subtypes or something like it. Every information that is bound to an element is written to its attributes. So the answer to the first question - no. The only correct way to work with it is to create the `type` attribute.

Networkx has only [[1]](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_edges_from.html#networkx.Graph.remove_edges_from) several [[2]](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.remove_nodes_from.html#networkx.Graph.remove_nodes_from) functions [[3]](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.subgraph.html#networkx.Graph.subgraph) to "filter" [[4]](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.edge_subgraph.html#networkx.Graph.edge_subgraph) graphs and all of them uses an iterable bunch of nodes/edges. So your solution is already sub-optimal. You can do some microoptimizations like:

`G.remove_edges_from([(x, y) for x, y, t in G.edges.data('type') if t == 1])`

or

`G.remove_edges_from(filter(lambda x: x[2] == 1, G.edges.data('type')))`

but nothing more. You can also refactor your main graph, but I am not sure you need it. Your code is pretty good already.